# A limit of an integral I

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be continuous and differentiable on $[0,1]$. Also let $0 \leq b \leq 1$. What is the resulting value of the limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{1}{n} \, \int_{0}^{1} f(b x^{2p}) \, g(x^{\frac{1}{n}}) \, dx \, ?
\end{align}
As an example of this limiting value what is the sign, $\epsilon$, in the result
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{1}{n} \, \int_{0}^{1} e^{-b x^{2}} \, \ln\left(1+ x^{\frac{1}{n}} \right) \, dx = \epsilon \, \frac{\zeta(2) \, e^{-b}}{2} \, ?
\end{align}

Comment: Due to the factor $b$ in the argument of $f$, either we need $0 \leqslant b \leqslant 1$, or $f$ needs to be defined (and continuous?) on $[0,b]$ or, if $b < 0$, $[b,0]$. If $f$ is continuous there, then $f$ and $g$ are bounded, so ... what? In your example, however, $g(x) = \ln (1-x)$ is not continuous on the closed interval.

Comment: @DanielFischer Good point. A correction has been made.

Comment: In your example you have $g(x) = \ln (1-x),$ which is not continuous on $[0,1].$

Comment: Is $\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{1}{n} \, \int_{0}^{1} e^{-b x^{2}} \, \ln\left(1+ x^{\frac{1}{n}} \right) \, dx$ actually $\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{1}{n} \, \int_{0}^{1} e^{-b x^{2}} \, \ln\left(1-x^{\frac{1}{n}} \right) \, dx$? Otherwise the integral is clearly $0$.